# How to add razor view file (.cshtml) in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am novice in MVC. I am just stuck in adding a .cshtml page in View.

I have created a Asp.Net MVC Web Application. When i  right click on View folder to add View, it adds a .aspx file as a view rather than a .cshtml file.

should i have to install anything to add a .cshtml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor view engine is only available from MVC version 3, if you are not using this version you cannot use razor view engine. get if from here [mvc 3 update for visual studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1491)

Answer (score 4):

you can add a view by **right clicking** on **View** folder click **Add** and select **View**
[image: Add View in vs 2013]

[image]

or **right clicking** on **View** folder click **Add** and select **New Item** and choose mvc template

Comment: I am doing that but it adds a .aspx file rather than the .cshtml file.

Comment: I change the answer. Is Razor view there in you **add item** dialog?

Comment: NO. There is nothing like this screen shot

Answer (score 1):

I think you didn't select razor view engine while creating project

[image]

[image]

Comment: when i am creating my MVC application, i don't see any option like this. There is no window appear like show in above screenshot

Comment: as @Venkatesh mentioned, its available from mvc version 3.are creating MVC 2 application? if so, download it from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=1491

Answer (score 0):

**This answer for visual studio 2022**

1. Right click folder, Go to "Add" and click "New Item"
   [image]

2.Search "razor" in here. and You can select "Razor View Start"

[image]

3. Click that. Now you can create ".cshtml" file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before create .cshtml you must to install ASP.NET. At this page you can by step create .cshtml file:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/05/16/vs2022-web-forms-tip.aspx